# background gradient with a strange 1px line

Tags: css

Strange 1px yellow line at the bottom:

[image: gradient-with-1px-line-bug]

If I use ctrl-minus to decrease the font size there is a line at the top:

[image: gradient-with-1px-line-bug-at-top]

For some zoom-values there is no strange 1px line.

CSS:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to left top,#fff 50%,transparent 50%),linear-gradient(to bottom,red 20%,#a8d695 20%);
```

What could be the reason?

I use Chrome: 97.0.4692.99

Comment: check the DevTools! if you couldn't fix it, attach some images in your question

Comment: @Sarout I checked with devtools and I attached two images.

Comment: For such a specific css issue, a [mre] would be very handy.

Comment: I know, I mean images from dev tools

Comment: Also, the 'yellow' (orange) line is probably the dev tools way of showing the margin!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Chrome does repeat the gradient.